# Explaining ingress installation with HELM

Tags: kubernetes, helm, ingress, kubernetes-helm

I was trying to install ingress helm charts but found a couple of tutorials but they just insert the different steps without proper explanation,  But I want to know what exactly each step means:

```
kubectl create namespace ingress-nginx
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx
```

In a simple words and correct me If I am wrong,
`kubectl create namespace ingress-nginx` -> this creates a namespace called `ingress-nginx`

`helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx` -> This add a chart repository called ingress-nginx from the URL mentioned (Am I free to name it to something else!?)

`helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx` -> install the chart named `ingress-nginx` (first one) , in the namespace called `ingress-nginx` (last one),
To be honest I can't understand it will, can anyone explains it?

and sometimes I see `helm repo update` after adding the chart-repo with `helm repo add` (inginx documentation is doing it) and sometimes not , what is the difference? is there any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explained what each does pretty well! I strongly suggest reading the documentation, especially for the commands, don't rely on tutorials only.[helm commands](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm/) `helm repo add` => This is what it stands for, it adds a new helm chart repository. `helm repo update` => Update gets the latest information about charts from the respective chart repositories. When you initially start or want to use a chart you will use `add`, let us say 6 months have passed, the chart has bugs that are now fixed in the latest version, you then use `update` to get the latest version. And you can use different names, see example => [helm examples](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/)

So what you explained yourself is pretty good, really.

1. You create a Kubernetes namespace.
2. You add a new repo for nginx.
3. Then you install that nginx repo in the new namespace you created in point (1). - otherwise, it will probably go in the default namespace. I always specify the namespace btw.

One thing to note, when you add a repo, it gets added locally and from there it gets installed. So when you do installations, helm goes through your local packages that are stored/cached and it installs them where you point them to.

Answer (score 0):

> In a simple words and correct me If I am wrong, kubectl create
> namespace ingress-nginx -> this creates a namespace called
> ingress-nginx

Correct !

> helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
> -> This add a chart repository called ingress-nginx from the URL mentioned (Am I free to name it to something else!?)

Correct too !
Yes, you can name it has you like, it's just the name that you'll use to refer to this repo url (e.g: in a requirement file)

> helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -n
> ingress-nginx -> install the chart named ingress-nginx (first one) ,
> in the namespace called ingress-nginx (last one), To be honest I can't
> understand it will, can anyone explains it?

Here, you tell to Helm "Install from a chart named 'ingress-nginx', from the 'ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx' (repository-name/chart-name get from ArtifactHub.io, the official Helm charts repository where you can find a lot of ready-to-use charts) repository, inside 'ingress-nginx' namespace".

> and sometimes I see helm repo update after adding the chart-repo with
> helm repo add (inginx documentation is doing it) and sometimes not ,
> what is the difference? is there any difference?

After the first "helm install", if you want to update your something like a simple value in your values.yaml file, you need to "helm upgrade" it, but it's only if you want to change the default config.
You can get more informations here : https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/

Hope it can help :)